# Creating columns to binarise dates in r

Tags: r, function

I have a data set:

```
Date    Customer ID Customer    Delivery City   Category
31/12/2015  14057267    a   NewCity Software - System Infrastructure
31/12/2015  14057267    a   NewCity Software - Information/Data Management
31/12/2015  14057267    a   NewCity Software - Information/Data Management
31/12/2015  14057267    b   NewCity Software - Information/Data Management
31/12/2015  14057267    b   OldCity Software - Information/Data Management
31/12/2015  14057267    c   OldCity Software - Information/Data Management
31/12/2015  14057267    c   OldCity Software - Information/Data Management
```

I want to create new columns based on the date so if the maximum date is 31. I need as many columns as the number days.The columns which will have 0 or 1 values depending on the day that's there in the date column for e.g. if day is 01 then `X_1=1` & remaining 31 days columns X_2 ... X31=0 .I want to binarise dates similarly I want to do that for the customer names say X_a,X_b,X_c which will also have values 0 & 1 .

Can someone help out ?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of you data (`dput(head(your_data))`) and the expected output?

Answer (score 2):

How about the following (just shown with 2 columns in the data frame):

```
# initial dataframe
head(df)
#  Date       Customer 
#1 01/12/2015        b
#2 02/12/2015        c
#3 03/12/2015        a
#4 04/12/2015        b
#5 05/12/2015        b
#6 06/12/2015        b

df$X <- substring(as.character(df$Date), 1, 2)
df <- cbind.data.frame(df, model.matrix(~X-1, df))[-3]

# final dataframe
head(df)
#  Date       Customer X01 X02 X03 X04 X05 X06 X07 X08 X09 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22 X23 X24 X25 X26 X27 X28 X29 X30 X31
#1 01/12/2015        c   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
#2 02/12/2015        a   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
#3 03/12/2015        a   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
#4 04/12/2015        b   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
#5 05/12/2015        c   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
#6 06/12/2015        a   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Thanks for sending this through however I have found a handy way :     for(level in unique(B2B_Data$Day)){
  B2B_Data[paste("Day", level, sep = "_")] <- ifelse(B2B_Data$Day == level, 1, 0)
}